# Logback-Slf4j writes log messages to file from when runs from IDe but not as a jar

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I am using SLF4j and logback to log messages. It works fine and writes to configured file. But when I build a executable jar and try to run from prompt as java -jar executableFile. It neither writes to configured file, also displays tons of debug messages on console.

this my logback.xml:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
          <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
  </appender>-->


<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/LogWriter/log-test.log </file>

    <append>true</append>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/var/log/LogWriter/log-test.log.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{36} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />


</root>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your main class is not finding logback.xml, so logback uses the default appender - the console in this case. You need to make sure that when packing the jar, the logback.xml is in the correct place.

Comment: You are welcome! According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty I guess I wouldn't seem to bad if I ask for upvote and accept :)

Comment: accepted the answer. Up-voted your answer at that time, since I am new user, that is why my upvote does not reflect.